# vue.js display json data

Tags: javascript, json, vue.js

[json data](https://api.douban.com/v2/movie/subject/25884801)

store

```
filmDetails: {}
......
getFilmDetail (context, param) {
     axios.get(API.filmDetails + param.id)
      .then(response => {
        context.commit('FILM_DETAILS', response.data)
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log(err)
      })
  }
```

.vue

```
<template>
  <section>
    <div v-for="item in filmDetails">
      <p>{{item.summary}}</p>
    </div>
  </section>
</template>
......
export default {
  name: 'detail',
  computed: {
    ...mapState(['filmDetails'])
  },
  mounted () {
    let _id = this.$route.params.id
    this.$store.dispatch('getFilmDetail', {
     id: _id
    })
  }
}
```

I wanna show some message on my page, like summary, but the chrome Dev tools console the 'Error in render function: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'summary' of null" ',

I tried.

Answer (score 2):

Set a guard to prevent render before items are fetched:

```
<template>
  <section v-if="filmDetails && filmDetails.length">
    <div v-for="item in filmDetails">
      <p>{{item.summary}}</p>
    </div>
  </section>
</template>
```

Comment: Yes, the chrome dev tools doesn't console the error, but the page is nothing,